# Combining multiple tXMLMap output values to a single snowflake table

Tags: xml, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, talend

I have the below XML structure as input

```
<dataexport>
<header>
     <companyinfo>
     <companyid> 100 </companyid>
     <companyname>ABC Corp</companyname>
     </companyinfo>
</header>
<deptinfo>
     <electrical>
          <response>
               <deptid> 1 </deptid>
               <totalemp> 200 </totalemp>
               <totalunits> 20 </totalunits>
          </response>
     </electrical>
     <mechanical>
          <response>
               <deptid> 2 </deptid>
               <totalemp> 150 </totalemp>
               <totalunits> 40 </totalunits>
          </response>
     </mechanical>
     <chemical>
          <response>
               <deptid> 3 </deptid>
               <totalemp> 100 </totalemp>
               <totalunits> 20 </totalunits>
          </response>
     </chemical>
```

The output that i am expecting is

| Company ID | Company name | Dept | Dept ID | Total emp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | ABC Corp | Electrical | 1 | 200 |
| 100 | ABC Corp | Mechanical | 2 | 150 |
| 100 | ABC Corp | Chemical | 3 | 100 |

The design approach I went with was as below -

[image]

tXMLMap component has been configured like below -

[image]

With this approach, I was able to get only one output and am unable to combine results of deptinfo_electrical, deptinfo_mechanical and deptinfo_chemical into one dataflow to load to a snowflake table.

Please advise what design approach can be used here.

Answer (score 0):

so using thia CTE with you data in it, in snowflake:

```
with data as (
    select parse_xml('<dataexport>
    <header>
         <companyinfo>
         <companyid> 100 </companyid>
         <companyname>ABC Corp</companyname>
         </companyinfo>
    </header>
    <deptinfo>
         <electrical>
              <response>
                   <deptid> 1 </deptid>
                   <totalemp> 200 </totalemp>
                   <totalunits> 20 </totalunits>
              </response>
         </electrical>
         <mechanical>
              <response>
                   <deptid> 2 </deptid>
                   <totalemp> 150 </totalemp>
                   <totalunits> 40 </totalunits>
              </response>
         </mechanical>
         <chemical>
              <response>
                   <deptid> 3 </deptid>
                   <totalemp> 100 </totalemp>
                   <totalunits> 20 </totalunits>
              </response>
         </chemical>
    </deptinfo>
    </dataexport>') as xml
)
```

this select gets you the values you want:

```
select xml
    ,xmlget(xmlget(xml,'header',0), 'companyinfo', 0) as comp
    ,get(xmlget(comp, 'companyid'),'$') as companyid
    ,get(xmlget(comp, 'companyname'), '$') as companyname
    ,get(d.value, '@') as depm
    ,xmlget(d.value, 'response') as r
    ,get(xmlget(r, 'deptid'),'$') as deptid
    ,get(xmlget(r, 'totalemp'), '$') as totalemp
    --,d.*
from data,
 LATERAL FLATTEN(GET(xmlget(xml,'deptinfo',0), '$')) d
```

so that is the form of the transformation you are wanting todo.

which can be restructured to:

```
select 
    get(xmlget(xmlget(xmlget(xml,'header',0), 'companyinfo', 0), 'companyid'),'$') as companyid
    ,get(xmlget(xmlget(xmlget(xml,'header',0), 'companyinfo', 0), 'companyname'), '$') as companyname
    ,get(d.value, '@') as depm
    ,get(xmlget(xmlget(d.value, 'response'), 'deptid'),'$') as deptid
    ,get(xmlget(xmlget(d.value, 'response'), 'totalemp'), '$') as totalemp
from data,
 LATERAL FLATTEN(GET(xmlget(xml,'deptinfo',0), '$')) d
```

to give the results:

```
COMPANYID   COMPANYNAME DEPM            DEPTID  TOTALEMP
100         "ABC Corp"  "electrical"    1       200
100         "ABC Corp"  "mechanical"    2       150
100         "ABC Corp"  "chemical"      3       100
```

how to actually do that in Talend, I have no answer, but I would assume you can look to see how your current pattern is run on Snowflake by looking at the query history, to solve how the parts map from Talend logic to snowflake SQL.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Simeon ! I am actually looking to implement using Talend components rather than Lateral Flatten function. Primary reason being the documentation of lateral flatten function is not clear or not understandable rather :( Would appreciate your help in understanding how to use the function better :)

Comment: @vvazza I have zero experience with Talend so cannot help there. Given how you wrote the question, it was rather obvious you wanted a solution in the tool. I was showing you how I would do it in SQL, so maybe it might help you explore the options in Talend. Thus why I said exactly that in the last paragraph. FLATTEN is not ready that hard a command, and given you are given an example. The XMLGET are much grosser commands I feel.

Comment: Simeon, how would I set the loop if I have one more set of data within electrical tag? If I have to loop <deptinfo> and <electrical> alone, should i LATERAL FLATTEN something like this - ```LATERAL FLATTEN(GET(xmlget(xmlget(xml,'deptinfo',0), 'electrical', '$')) d```?

Comment: Flatten has a parameter that say, return one row if input is null, this is useful if `mech` and `chem` dont have the sub loop. `OUTER=>true` is what you want then you can `from data,  LATERAL FLATTEN(GET(xmlget(xml,'deptinfo',0), '$')) d, LATERAL  FLATTEN(input=> d.<the_thing_it_has> outer=>true)) e` and for the `elec` row e.value will not be null, thus you can select those subobjects. @vvazza